# Any frameworks for dynamically creating schema on-the-fly to support adhoc JSON object map persistence?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, dao

Here is a requirement that I am trying to nail down - there is this incoming JSON data which represents an Object Map (think nested objects, each having one or more attributes) which I need to persist in my database.  Now the problem is that I do not know what attributes are going to come-in in the JSON data.  I need to dynamically build tables as well as the columns when the data comes-in and it is okay to just create all string type columns to start with.  But if the next request has more attributes for given object-type, or, less attributes, but just different set of attributes, then the corresponding table that was created earlier should automatically be expanded to add new columns to it and then allow persistence of incoming JSON data.  For nested objects, each object should go into separate table and it is okay if some sort of join or mapping table gets created additionally to maintain the mapping between the two.  The objects will have static "id" attribute, which may have some numeric number.  This needs to be treated specially, in the sense that the object having no "id" attribute should be considered "new" object, hence row insert should be performed, and id should be generated for the object during persistence.  If the object already has "id" attribute populated, then it should be considered as update operation.  There is another special attribute called "toBeDeleted=true|false" which may show up in JSON object map, which should end up triggering (cascade) delete on the object identified by the id.

Now here is the question: Is there any OR mapping framework, which allows on-the-fly expanding the schema to persist incoming attributes?  Has anyone dealt with this kind of requirement where the schema is not fixed and needs to expand on the fly to accommodate the incoming data - are there any frameworks that support this type of JSON persistence behavior?

Keep in mind, I am trying not to create tables with key/value columns to store the attributes and values for each object, because that usually results in 'tall' tables, which don't perform well for retrieval performance. I really would like to see each attribute getting persisted in it's own column, not as a row in the key/value pair type table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to make an ORM store data it's not designed to store, which is a more of a flat db or a document store. I would reconsider your design as it sounds like something like Mongo would be more suited as it will do what you're asking out of the box.

Comment: Yeah you're right about MongoDB.  Also read up on CloudDB and it seems like these databases have such features supported OOTB. Great! I should be able to code up JSON aware UI directly against CloudDB REST services. Thanks for your response.